# Windows 8.1 PHP PDO connection issues again

Tags: php

This is the common error often reported in questions:

```
SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Please assume correctly that I've been reading posts for ... 'days'!

I've done all the following:

1) Uncommented: `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll` in `php.ini`

2) Set-up a system DSN in `SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

3) Checked that `odbcjt32.dll` is present in `SysWOW64`

My standard (latest PHP) code:

```
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {die("Could not find database file.");}
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$dbq;Uid=$user;Pwd=$password");
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

There is no file_exists error (so addressing isn't the issue)
The .mdb is mine (so I know the correct Uid/Pwd)
The .mdb is in the same inetpub folder as the .php file calling it (so not permissions)
In windows powershell, I've run: Get-OdbcDsn which correctly shows the rich1 system DSN:

```
Name       : rich1
DsnType    : System
Platform   : 32-bit
DriverName : Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
Attribute  : {DBQ, DriverId, ImplicitCommitSync, Threads...}
```

Still the same error :-( so I'm dead ended.

Does anyone know of any more 'Get-OdbcDsn' type routines that will help diagnose what's going on? Or any kind of new tack that leads me away from this dead end?

Comment: Presumably you are running PHP in a 32-bit process otherwise you wouldn't be so hung up on the 32-bit versions of odbcad.exe, right?

Comment: What's `$dbq` in this example? If you're using a DSN you've configured in `odbcac32.exe` I'd expect to see something like `odbc:rich1` (from the first example http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php) not a connection string.

Comment: Hmm. I'm running the IIS Application Pools default set to Enable 32-Bit Applications 'True', but as you've correctly alluded, the PHP install is 64-bit - I think you've spotted the blindingly obvious that's alluded this poor fool! Assuming that all it is, I hope the small catalogue of steps above helps others, and thanks ta.speot.is!

Comment: I've just remembered why I was doing this - the .mdb is created/used by an older application, so is 32-bit. I'm now assuming that my 64-bit php will never connect, not even with the 64-Bit Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb) DSN in ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-Bit). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: To my knowledge an mdb file doesn't have a bit-ness. You can use JET (32-bit only) or ACE (32-bit or 64-bit http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13255 see AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe ... there's also a 2013 version too I think) to connect to it without issue.

Comment: Thanks ta.speot.is - this thread has nailed it. In the end I made sure everything was 64-bit (no messing with IIS), set a system DSN called rich1 in the system32\odbcad32.exe including the user Admin and password, and used $dbh = new PDO("odbc:rich1"); - no errors ;-)